# Bluetooth, two sources to two different ouputs simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, playback

i want to play sound from two different sources to two different Bluetooth simultaneously.
Can this be done?
With Bluetooth-5 you can connect two speakers simultaneously, can i target my output to one of the channels.

- Source a, a sound player plays voice A to speaker A
- Source b, a sound player plays voice B to speaker B

Comment: Hello, which system? What's the BT version of all the devices? Are the output devices from same manufacturer and do they have any software that could help achieving this scenario? This question is missing a bunch of important details.

Comment: @Destroy666 I dont have the details of hardware, i just want to know if it can be done, if so then i will buy the appropriate hardware.

Comment: Then the short answer is "yes". You'll need to be way more specific to also get more specific answers. Otherwise this falls under software/hardware recommendation questions, which are disallowed on this site.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thanks for the feedback, will ask my question there

Comment: @Destroy666 Hi, could you please send me in the right direction where to look. It will be for windows or imac to send different sound to different speakers.

Comment: I see you asked on harware recommendations, I'll try to answer there around this weekend.